# How to use Main from another Class in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, actionscript, flashdevelop

Could someone help me with calling Main constructor? In general my idea is to reset scene.

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Sprite
{
    private var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function Main()
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point          

        sprite.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x990000, 1);
        sprite.graphics.drawRoundRect(5, 5, 500, 150, 10, 10);
        addChild(sprite);
    }
}
```

By using a button I removed that sprite, and my scene goes to blank, but i have another class:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    public function Action()
    {
        ResetMain();
    }

    private function ResetMain()
    {
        //what to write here for reseting Main(re-calling Main()) ?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose, if you really wanted to, you could remove the document class and re-instantiate it:

```
//a function in your Main class that resets itself:
public function resetMain()
{
    var s:Stage = stage; //need a temporary reference to the stage
    parent.removeChild(this); //remove the Main class from the stage
    s.addChild(new Main()); //add a new instance of the Main class
}
```

This is an odd way to reset your program though, and I wouldn't recommend it. You'll loose the use of the `root` keyword doing this. Any event listeners not weakly referenced or explicitly removed would also cause memory leaks.

It would be better to just write a function that resets all your stuff, instead of re-calling the Main contructor by re-instantiating the document class (Main class)

```
private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    // entry point          

    reset(); 
}

public function reset():void {
    //clear out any vars/display objects if they exist already
    if(sprite) removeChild(sprite);  

    //now create those objects again
    sprite = new Sprite();
    sprite.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x990000, 1);
    sprite.graphics.drawRoundRect(5, 5, 500, 150, 10, 10);
    addChild(sprite);
}
```

---

From your comments, it sounds like you just need a way to reference your main class from `AnotherClass`.

There are a few ways you can accomplish this.

1. Pass a reference to AnotherClass when you create it. You don't show how you create AnotherClass, but you could change it's constructor to take in a reference of the Main instance:

   ```
   public class AnotherClass
   {
       private var main:Main;

       public function AnotherClass(main_:Main){
           this.main = main_;
       }

       //....rest of class code
   ```

   Then when you instantiate AnotherClass, pass in the reference:

   ```
   var another:AnotherClass = new AnotherClass(this); //assuming your in the main class with this line of code
   ```
2. Use the `root` keyword.

   The root keyword gains you a reference to the documentClass (what I assume Main is).   So from any class that is on the display list, you could do:

   ```
   Main(root).reset();
   ```
3. Make a static reference to the Main instance

   Static methods and variables are accessed using the class itself (not an instance of the class).  So you could do something like this:

   ```
   public class Main extends Sprite
   {
       public static var me:Main; //a static var to hold the instance of the main class
       public function Main()
       {
           me = this; //assign the static var to the instance of Main
           //.... rest of Main class code
   ```

   Then you can do this from anywhere in the application:

   ```
   Main.me.reset();
   ```

Comment: I do as you sujest, but error accure: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. In AnotherClass.as I created variable, "private var main:Main;" and call reset() - "main.reset();" in Action func. and that error popups.

Comment: I think is happens because of main == null, but how to call reset() w\o it i do not know ... In AnotherClass.as I transfer "this"(from Main.as) as "DisplayObjectContainer" for adding elements on scene from AnotherClass.as

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. All of them are works fine, but could you help me with understanding how it works ... For example. I have an AnotherClass, there "public var main_class:Main;" and I call it from Main like that: "var something:AnotherClass = new AnotherClass(); something.main_class = this;". So it works fine, but only once. Why ? Because I use function 'ClearAll', that remove all children/events and variables from scene. If I stoped to 'null' all varialbes in a class - all works fine no matter how did i you it (your variation or mine).

Comment: Its like I need to use "new" statment in inside function, but not outside them as I do it now.